# When changing one input value then the other one changes too

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a Sudoku game. At the moment I am getting in array and building GUI based on that. The bug happens when I use event listener on input fields- every time I change any input then the bottom right one changes as well. I cannot figure out why it is happening, can anyone help please?

```
class Sudoku {
  newGame (newBoard) {
    let td, tr, inputEl;
    let table = document.createElement('table');
    table.classList.add('sudoku-container')

    // Go over the rows
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      tr = document.createElement('tr');

      // Go over columns
      for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        // Build the input
        inputEl = document.createElement('input');
        inputEl.setAttribute('maxlength', 1);
        inputEl.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
          inputEl.value = e.target.value;
        });

        // If input value is not 0 then show value
        if (newBoard[i][j]) {
          inputEl.value = newBoard[i][j];
          inputEl.setAttribute('readonly', true);
        }

        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(inputEl);

        // Calculate the section ID
        let sectIDi = Math.floor(i / 3);
        let sectIDj = Math.floor(j / 3);
        // Set the design for different sections
        if ((sectIDi + sectIDj) % 2 === 0) {
          td.classList.add('sudoku-section-one');
        } else {
          td.classList.add('sudoku-section-two');
        }

        // Build the row
        tr.appendChild(td);
      }
      // Append to table
      table.appendChild(tr);
      document.querySelector('body').appendChild(table);

    }
    // Return the GUI table
    return table;
  }
}
```

Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h9gab7jz/1/

Comment: your re-use of the inputEl variable is causing this. changing the arrow function to a function keyword and using `this` to target the input element fixes it. https://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/nyakcLoh/

Comment: Thanks a lot :)!